# What is the CS definition of a Php Array?

Tags: php, data-structures, computer-science

From a strictly implementation and computer science point of view how would you classify the Php array datastructure? Is it an associative array? a hash? a dictionary? ... ?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247467

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered
> map. A map is a type that associates
> values to keys. This type is optimized
> for several different uses; it can be
> treated as an array, list (vector),
> hash table (an implementation of a
> map), dictionary, collection, stack,
> queue, and probably more.

Comment: The question was about the implementation. How can one know which operations on a PHP array are O(1) and what the efficiency of other operations is?

Comment: Hmm, I bet it can't quite behave like my favorite, the dequeue!

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on how you wish to classify it. I'd opt for classification by the performance of operations.

For example, a true array in Computer Science terms has an O(1) lookup time, while a linked list has an O(n) lookup time. Insertion and deletion are O(1) in a linked list while they are O(n) in an array.

I am not sure what the actual performance of a PHP array is, but if you measure a few of the elementary operations on them and compare them with what's expected from the 'true Computer Science datastructures' you should be able to classify it.

Comment: Not a bad idea, however hardware optimizations tend to get in the way of algorithmic performance, so its not always trivial, or even possible to determine the Big-O of an implementation, looking at its performance, as cache hits and CPU pipelining stuff screw the results.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to define it in my opinion. Although, I think I would classify it as an associative array since most of the defined operations for an associative array are available on PHP arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to define really. A *dictionary* or *map* refers to the behaviour of the datatype, while a *hashmap* refers to a specific implementation hereof. The term *array* is a bit tinted - Strictly speaking, it refers to a concrete implementation, whereas a *list* is a generic term that refers to any array-like datatype. It's however quite common to use *array* as a synonym for *list*.