# How does PHP handle integer indexed non-consecutive keyed arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, array-key

I'm curious as to how efficient it is in PHP to store an array with integer indices that are non-consecutive.

If I had an array

```
$b = array();
$b[1] = "Hello";
$b[18] = "World";
$b[999] = "Test";
```

Are those keys stored, and then hashed to a new array, how does PHP handle this?

Comment: Duplicate, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247467/how-are-associative-arrays-implemented-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [php wep site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) on array:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

Executing print_r($b); on your code gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Hello
    [18] => World
    [999] => Test
)
```

Comment: I need to create an array like this.  I am storing values to mysql record IDs to later be processed.  However in my case, the mysql record IDs start at like 100,000 and go up - so an array would be `$ar = array([100001] => "Blah", [305278] = "Foo", [412731] = "FooBar")` so later I can just reference the array as `$ar[$recordID]`