# data structure to add element in associative array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are associative arrays implemented in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247467/how-are-associative-arrays-implemented-in-php)

Can anybody help me out to understand the data structure behind the associative array.I have tried to find it out from the last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

It is an ordered hash map. Here is rhe creator of php saying so: http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg59849.html

Answer (score 0):

In computing, a hash table (also hash map) is a data structure used to implement an associative array, a structure that can map keys to values.

Please refer the following wiki link for more details

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table